# Stream Live WebRTC not working in Safari iOS the Google Nest Cam Battery

Tags: javascript, google-api, stream, webrtc

I would get the stream live of Google Nest Cam Battery (New). To this I use WebRTC. It's the protocol supported by Google Nest Cam. It's work on android, PCs but not on iPhone. I tried RTCPeerConnection - Simplepeer. But I can't get the stream live on iPhone - iOS. I alo used a adapter JS taht I found. But nothing work on iPhone.

The code that I use :

```
    <video id="webCamVideo" controls autoplay playsinline loop width="80%" /><br>

<script src="webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        const configuration = {
            iceServers: [
                {
                    urls: [
                        'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                        'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
                    ],
                },
            ],
            iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
        };

        let peerConnection = null;
        let remoteStream = null;

        async function startFeed() {
            peerConnection = new window.RTCPeerConnection(configuration); // Utilisation de window pour RTCPeerConnection
            const token = '<?php echo($_COOKIE["acto"]); ?>';
            const projectid = "<?php echo($project_id); ?>";
            const deviceid = "<?php echo($deviceid); ?>";

            remoteStream = new MediaStream();
            const videoElement = document.querySelector('#webCamVideo');
            if (videoElement) {
                videoElement.srcObject = remoteStream;
            }

            // Watch for new tracks from remote stream; add to video stream
            peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
                event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
                    remoteStream.addTrack(track);
                });
            };

            // Data Channel Required by the SDM API.
            if (peerConnection.createDataChannel) {
                peerConnection.createDataChannel("dataSendChannel");
            }

            try {
                // Create the offer.
                const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer({
                    offerToReceiveAudio: true,
                    offerToReceiveVideo: true
                });
                await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

                // Safari doesn't respect the parameter requests of createOffer above, so let's fudge the offer ourselves!
                let offerSdp = offer.sdp;
                offerSdp = offerSdp.replace('a=sendrecv', 'a=recvonly');

                // Now, send request for SDP connection
                const url = "https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/" + projectid + "/devices/" + deviceid + ":executeCommand";
                const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "command": "sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream",
                        "params": {
                            "offerSdp": offerSdp
                        }
                    })
                };
                const response = await fetch(url, options);

                // Process the response.
                const data = await response.json();
                let answerSdp = data.results.answerSdp;

                // Now start the feed using the answer
                const answer = new window.RTCSessionDescription({ type: 'answer', sdp: answerSdp }); // Utilisation de window pour RTCSessionDescription
                await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error starting feed:", error);
            }
        }

        // Call startFeed when the page is loaded.
        window.addEventListener('load', startFeed);

        </script>
```

I added alert command in the code for detect the issue.

The code :

```
alert("6");
const data = await response.json();
let answerSdp = data.results.answerSdp;
alert("7");
```

I get the alert 6 but not the 7.

How I can resolve this?
Thanksss.

Comment: Can you describe where the failure occurs, perhaps by adding additional tracing to your code?

Comment: @spender I will post all the code complet. It's works on androic, pcs. But on iphone the video element it's gray.

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone will take a big splat of code and try to figure out where the problem is. There are plenty of points in the code that you could measure to find out exactly where the problem occurs. This will significantly increase your chances of other users interacting with this question.

Comment: @spender Ok you are right. I will only post the javascript code and i will test with alert commands for detect where is the problem-issue

Comment: IDK enough about this to help I'm afraid. Just trying to guide you to a better experience on SO :)

Comment: @spender OK. I understand. Thanks you.